# jQuery datepicker alignment issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI library for date-picker functionality.

Here is the website url that i've developed: http://redfruit.in/site/lorem.html

As you see there is two text-field with calendar icon. If you click on text-area, calendar[for date selection] pop-up.

This functionality works perfectly on Full-HD devices and mobile devices but it's not working on standard HD display[1366 x 768].

Only the inner date-picker labeled with "Check" works but when i click on the text-field labeled with "Chk",calendar goes outside the container.

[Reduce the width to 1366 with Inspect Element and click on the text-field labeled with "Chk"]

I already inspect it but the CSS styles are applied inside the html tag so i can't control the position of calendar.

Is there any way to fix this issue??

Thanks in Advance for your effort.

Comment: I opened the link you used and using the inspector changed my dimensions to 1366 x 768 but it seems to be working fine. Please can you be more specific to help with finding the issue you're having.

Comment: You have to add your code to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style, this might help,

```
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 160px !important;
}
```

make sure you have added the style in proper `@media` statement.
I have tested in Full HD, 1366 monitor. Screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: Works Perfectly.Thanks for the suggestion.